Variables not updating in tensorflow model and not registering as trainable params
I have simplified my original code to a regression example for secrecy. I constructed this model in file called Reg.py.
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers,optimizers,Model,initializers
class regression():
    def __init__(self):


        x = layers.Input(dtype = tf.float64 ,shape = (1,), name="x")
        self.m = tf.Variable(0.1, dtype=tf.float64, trainable=True)
        self.b = tf.Variable(0.1, dtype=tf.float64, trainable=True)

        y = self.m*x+self.b


        self.model    = Model(inputs = [x], outputs = y)
        
        # specify the optimizer and loss function for training 
        self.model.compile(optimizer=optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01), loss='mse', metrics=['mse'])
        
        # print a summary of the model showing the layers, their connections, and the number of training parameters
        self.model.summary()

When I try to train the variables m and b, they don't change:
x = [i for i in range(10)]
y = [5*i+3 for i in x]

reg = regression()

gives
WARNING:tensorflow:The following Variables were used in a Lambda layer's call (tf.__operators__.add_1), but are not present in its tracked objects:   <tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=() dtype=float64>. This is a strong indication that the Lambda layer should be rewritten as a subclassed Layer.
WARNING:tensorflow:The following Variables were used in a Lambda layer's call (tf.__operators__.add_1), but are not present in its tracked objects:   <tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=() dtype=float64>. This is a strong indication that the Lambda layer should be rewritten as a subclassed Layer.
WARNING:absl:At this time, the v2.11+ optimizer `tf.keras.optimizers.Adam` runs slowly on M1/M2 Macs, please use the legacy Keras optimizer instead, located at `tf.keras.optimizers.legacy.Adam`.
WARNING:absl:There is a known slowdown when using v2.11+ Keras optimizers on M1/M2 Macs. Falling back to the legacy Keras optimizer, i.e., `tf.keras.optimizers.legacy.Adam`.
Model: "model_20"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 x (InputLayer)              [(None, 1)]               0         
                                                                 
 tf.math.multiply_2 (TFOpLam  (None, 1)                0         
 bda)                                                            
                                                                 
 tf.__operators__.add_1 (TFO  (None, 1)                0         
 pLambda)                                                        
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 0
Trainable params: 0
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________

and reg.model.fit() is not changing the variables. Does anyone know why/how to fix this so the variables are optimized?
I originally didn't have trainable  = True but I added that and it changed nothing
